# On form submit trigger to assign numbers to records

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

Updated:

Please see the sample google spreadsheet link below
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YLM8ydXWalvCzsyMkQ20-dgAPBFeVKKUtHp_53KybbY/edit?usp=sharing

Please take a look at
Row 1514,1767,1971,2619,2654

---

I am trying to use a Google Form to record a membership database.
I want to assign a membership number to each submitted record, starting from 1 then 2 then 3 etc...
It works well but I got occasional missing numbers and I got something like this

Case 1 - completely missed assignment

Members E ---1

Members F ---2

Members G ---

Members H ---3

Or

Case 2 - partly missed assignment

Members A ---1

Members B ---2

Members C ---

Members D ---4

Member C got an "empty" membership number. It seems like the following code failed to run

```
dbs.getRange(dbs.getLastRow(),7).setValue(lastMembershipID)
```

But `membershipIdCell.setValue(membershipCountID +1)` will still run so the membership number is added by 1 although it was not assigned to member C. How can I solve it? Now I will just manually put "3" on the member C membership number cell. Below is the full code and with trigger on form submit. Thank you!

```
const ws = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
const ss = ws.getSheetByName("Option")
const dbs = ws.getSheetByName("Membership DB")

    
    function assignMembershipID (){
      var membershipIdCell = ss.getRange("C2")
      var membershipCountID = membershipIdCell.getValue()
    
      var fullMembershipIdCell = ss.getRange("D2")
      var lastMembershipID = fullMembershipIdCell.getValue()
      dbs.getRange(dbs.getLastRow(),7).setValue(lastMembershipID)
    
      membershipIdCell.setValue(membershipCountID +1)
    
    }
```

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of the Google Form. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: "Below is the full code..." Um, no it isn't the "full code". Where is `ss` defined, ditto `dbs`? Please show the ENTIRE full code, including the bits that don't seem important. AAMOI, what is the data in cell "C2", and have you considered using [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit) to identify the edited row?

Comment: Sorry for my poor quality question. I have updated with the sample google spreadsheet above. Please kindly review again